# Convert UTC timestamp to local time based on time zone in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame, `df`, with some columns as shown below. The `hour` column is in UTC time and I want to create a new column that has the local time based on the `time_zone` column. How can I do that in PySpark?

```
df
    +-------------------------+------------+
    |  hour                   | time_zone  |
    +-------------------------+------------+
    |2019-10-16T20:00:00+0000 | US/Eastern |
    |2019-10-15T23:00:00+0000 | US/Central |
    +-------------------------+------------+

#What I want:
    +-------------------------+------------+---------------------+
    |  hour                   | time_zone  | local_time          |
    +-------------------------+------------+---------------------+
    |2019-10-16T20:00:00+0000 | US/Eastern | 2019-10-16T15:00:00 |
    |2019-10-15T23:00:00+0000 | US/Central | 2019-10-15T17:00:00 |
    +-------------------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the in-built [`from_utc_timestamp`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_utc_timestamp.html) function. Note that the `hour` column needs to be passed in as a string *without timezone* to the function.

Code below works for spark versions starting 2.4.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.select(from_utc_timestamp(split(df.hour,'\+')[0],df.time_zone).alias('local_time')).show()
```

For spark versions before 2.4, you have to pass in a constant string representing the time zone, as the second argument, to the function.

**[`Documentation`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions)**

**`pyspark.sql.functions.from_utc_timestamp(timestamp, tz)`**

> This is a common function for databases supporting TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE. This function takes a timestamp which is timezone-agnostic, and interprets it as a timestamp in UTC, and renders that timestamp as a timestamp in the given time zone.

> However, timestamp in Spark represents number of microseconds from the Unix epoch, which is not timezone-agnostic. So in Spark this function just shift the timestamp value from UTC timezone to the given timezone.

> This function may return confusing result if the input is a string with timezone, e.g. ‘2018-03-13T06:18:23+00:00’. The reason is that, Spark firstly cast the string to timestamp according to the timezone in the string, and finally display the result by converting the timestamp to string according to the session local timezone.

> Parameters
> timestamp – the column that contains timestamps

> tz – a string that has the ID of timezone, e.g. “GMT”, “America/Los_Angeles”, etc

> **Changed in version 2.4: tz can take a Column containing timezone ID strings.**

Comment: Had to format the date to include the +0800 - "date_format(from_utc_timestamp('2023-01-16 21:40:00.0', 'Asia/Singapore'), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+0800") as timestamp_sgt"

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to use a spark UDF.

```
from pytz import timezone
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
def mytime(x,y):
    dt = datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
    return dt.astimezome(timezone(y))
mytimeUDF = udf(mytime, StringType())
df = df.withColumn('local_time', mytimeUDF("hour","timezone"))
```